# char pointer interpretation in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm sort of new to C. So, dumb question alert! I would like to understand how the following statements are interpreted by the compiler.

```
char *str="string1";
*str = "string2";   --> Gives a segmentation fault
puts(ptr);
```

whereas this works

```
char *ptr="string1";
puts(ptr);
ptr="string2";
puts(ptr);
```

Comment: A tip: Crank up the warning-level. Your compiler should then complain about the first code.

Comment: Yeah, just compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Wall` and you'll be saved from much nonsense.

Comment: In the first block "str" is declared as a pointer to a string. Its better to look at it like char *   str = "string"; So str is the variable and later *str  means something different (read up on use of pointers). In the second example you did it OK.

Comment: @bcperth: *"str" is declared as a pointer to a string*" no. `str` is a pointer to `char`. A `char` is exactly *one* character. In C there is no data type "*string*".

Comment: `ptr` and `*str` obviously are not the same. You want to read about "dereferencing", done by the ["indirection"-operator `*`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2).

Comment: @alk 100% my bad. Lazy wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
*str = "string2";   --> Gives a segmentation fault
```

should be written like this:

```
str = "string2";
```

The *str* identifier is of the type *char**, that is, pointer to *char*. To avoid the mistake, you can write like this:

```
char* str;
```

Also, you are assigning a *constant* string to the variable. So, if you want to assign a modifiable string to *str*, use strcpy (string copy):

```
char str[40];
strcpy(str, "My string");
str[2] = '_'; //replacing space with underscore
```

Comment: Your last example is writing to read-only memory, and would break the array size anyway.

Comment: @judismar thank you.  So, when I say `char* str="string1";` the compiler stores "string1" as an unnamed *constant* object and assigns the address of that location to pointer str. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Precisely, @enthusiast. You wouldn't be able to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str="string1";
*str = "string2";   --> Gives a segmentation fault
puts(ptr);
```

Your assignment `*str = "string2";` is a *constraint violation*.

The C standard (perhaps unfortunately) doesn't require C compilers to reject incorrect programs. It does require diagnostic messages for certain kinds of errors, but in some cases not all compilers even do that. You should find out what options to use to get it to diagnose more errors.

If your compiler did give you a warning message, *don't ignore it*. Warnings from C compiler might be about minor stylistic issues, or they might be about things that you'd expect to be treated as fatal errors. You'll need to learn how to tell the difference.

`*str` is of type `char`. `"string2"` is a string literal, and it's of type `char[8]`, and array of `char`. But in most contexts (this is another odd thing about C), an expression of array type is treated as an expression of pointer type. So `"string2"` is treated as an expression yielding a result of type `char*`, a pointer to the `'s'` in `"string2"`.

C doesn't support assignment for arrays.

It doesn't make sense to assign a pointer value to a `char` object (a small integer) -- but old versions of C, from decades ago, didn't make a strong distinction between integers and pointers. Ideally a modern C compiler should just reject the assignment because of the type conflict, but yours is generating code that takes an address of type `char*`, treats it as an integer, truncates that integer value to store in a single byte, and *tries* to store it in the 0th element of the array. (You could still do that in modern C with a cast, an explicit conversion, but you don't want to do that anyway.)

So why the segmentation fault? String literals are read-only. (Well, sort of, long story; they're not guaranteed to be read-only, but they often are.) So the chunk of memory holding the array `"string1"` is protected by the operating system against being modified. A segmentation fault, killing your program, is how the OS responds when you try to bypass that protection.

Incidentally, that last line should be `puts(str);`, not `puts(ptr);`. When posting a question here, it's always best to copy and paste the *exact* code that you compiled. If there are errors, we need to know whether they're errors in your actual code or just typos.

Comment: thanks a lot for the thorough explanation!  And I will make a note of your comment on the `puts(ptr)` typo.

Answer (score -2):

*str = "string2";   --> Gives a segmentation fault because you are trying to assign a value of multiple chars to the char pointer *str which should return only one char value,since its a char pointer not a string pointer.

char *ptr="string2";

This statement works because you are initializing it at the time of declaration and hence, it works.

Comment: No, I think Compiler treats it differently
    `char* str="string";`
    `*str='a';`
Above code fails. Where as this works
`char mystring[]="samplestring";`
`char *str=&mystring[0];`
`*str='a';`